# Running powershell commands as another user

Tags: powershell, active-directory, restore

I'm trying to restore a test user from the deleted objects OU and do so with a test account. The problem is that I cannot get the test account to run the command without running into an *"Access is denied"* error. The test user is part of a group to restore users from the deleted objects OU as I am, and I'm able to run the same command just fine. I think I'm doing something wrong with `$cred`, but can't figure out what.

```
$Cred = get-adobject -ldapfilter "(samaccountname=LOOKATME)" -includedeletedobjects -credential "testyboi" | restore-adobject
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

So you need to create the credential variable using

```
$cred = Get-Credential
```

Then you need to use that variable as the -credential parameter in your command.

```
get-adobject -ldapfilter "(samaccountname=LOOKATME)" -includedeletedobjects -credential 
$cred | restore-adobject
```

Comment: This made a big difference, now the accounts are searching and finding the deleted accounts! (when not using |restore-adobject) but still saying access is denied when i try to restore it like above.

Comment: @john99988 unfortunately I can't troubleshoot permissions issues very easily. Try using the fully qualified domain name when you enter your credentials ("testyboi@mydomain.com" instead of "testyboi") You could make a new question for the account permission problem. I'm glad I could fix your code :)